# Develop a editable website for admin to edit the content on the web, without edit the source code by hand

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project that required to develop websites which allow admin users (who have no IT background) to edit content of the website (ex: post blog, edit title, update images, add more categories) on the website without coding. Is it possible to do it uses only front-end(html js) because the project is to add to a existing BIG ASP web app which i have no access (old developers left and the remain teams don't know what going on) and i have no experience with this kind of project before and have little times to do the project. Can you give me advice ?

Comment: Sounds like it's time for website 2.0 with a full fledged and integrated CMS system.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Front-end code runs in the browser.

The browser is under the control of the visitor, not the site owner.

The browser does not have the power to freely edit websites so that other people can see the changes.

If it did, Google.com would be defaced approximately once every half second.

---

You need to do this on the server.

> i have no access (old developers left and the remain teams don't know what going on) and i have no experience with this kind of project before and have little times to do the project. Can you give me advice ?

Hire the old developers back as contractors until they've transferred enough knowledge about the system so you can do any future work. Don't let the skills leave the organisation without a knowledge transfer again.

Comment: "Don't let the skills leave the organisation without a knowledge transfer again." - this can not be emphasized enough!

Comment: I am only an intern and this project is confusing. I do not have the permission to access the server and they ask me to develop it without server config. The remain team have no experience with web development which makes me more confuse.

Comment: @LDTuan — Either (1) You have misunderstood the limits they have imposed upon you or (2) They have given you an impossible task. Either way, you need to talk to them to fix it. Stackoverflow can't help.